# IfcRoof won't work without own ShapeRepresentation

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

I've tried to  create a flatroof with an IfcSlab. The IfcRoof is supposed to be decomposed by the IfcSlab. I created the slab with a ShapeRepresentation and gave it coordinates. BuidlingSMART is saying that I don't need a ShapeRespresentation for my roof when the slab already has one. But appenrtly it doesn't work when I run my application and try to see my model in the Xplorer. The roof isn't there, but when I create an own ShapeRepresentation for the roof it works.

This is how I wanted to create the roof with the slab:

```
var aggregation = model.Instances.New<IfcRelAggregates>();
                aggregation.RelatingObject = slabRoof;
                aggregation.RelatedObjects.Add(roof);
```

Is there a way to create this flatroof without an extra ShapeRepresentation for the roof like it's written in buildingSMART?

Answer (score 0):

You may have inverted the aggregation relation. For `IfcRelAggregates`, the `RelatingObject` side should refer to the whole (that is `IfcRoof`) and the `RelatedObjects` side should refer to the parts (that is `IfcSlab`). If you do it the other way round, the viewer will not find any parts of the roof with geometry and show nothing.